# Trouble creating SalesOrder with Quickbooks and VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, quickbooks, qbfc

I'm having trouble creating a sales order using QBFC15 and VB.Net into Quickbooks Enterprise 22.  I can connect to QB and create a job for an existing customer with the following code:

```
Dim msgSetRs As IMsgSetResponse
Try
    sessManager = New QBSessionManagerClass()
    sessManager.OpenConnection("App", "Admin to Quickbooks Utility")
    sessManager.BeginSession("", ENOpenMode.omDontCare)
    Console.WriteLine("Quickbook COM Session Opened")
Catch
    Console.WriteLine("Quickbook COM Error: " + Err.Description)
    Return
End Try

Dim msgSetRq As IMsgSetRequest = sessManager.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 15, 0)
msgSetRq.Attributes.OnError = ENRqOnError.roeContinue

Dim custAdd As ICustomerAdd = msgSetRq.AppendCustomerAddRq

custAdd.Name.SetValue(JobName)
custAdd.ParentRef.FullName.SetValue(String.Format("{0}", StoreName))
custAdd.BillAddress.Addr1.SetValue(String.Format("{0}", StoreName))
msgSetRs = sessManager.DoRequests(msgSetRq)
```

Note in the above, Storename = "MyStore.com" and Jobname = "Job - 1001"

When I try to create a sales order for that job, the code below does not give an error, but no sales order appears in QB.

I am reusing the same QBSession if that matters.

My subroutine's part to add a Sales Order

```
Dim requestMsgSet As IMsgSetRequest = sessManager.CreateMsgSetRequest("US",15,0)
requestMsgSet.Attributes.OnError = ENRqOnError.roeContinue

Dim SalesOrderAddRq As ISalesOrderAdd

SalesOrderAddRq = requestMsgSet.AppendSalesOrderAddRq()
SalesOrderAddRq.CustomerRef.FullName.SetValue(StoreName + ":" + JobName)
SalesOrderAddRq.TxnDate.SetValue(Date.Parse(OrderDate)) 'OrderDate is a DateTime = 3/9/2022 12:31:09 PM
SalesOrderAddRq.RefNumber.SetValue(MainOrderId.ToString) 'OrderID is an integer = 123456 
SalesOrderAddRq.BillAddress.Addr1.SetValue(StoreName)
SalesOrderAddRq.DueDate.SetValue(Date.Parse(OrderDate))

Dim SalesOrderAddLn As ISalesOrderLineAdd

SalesOrderAddLn = SalesOrderAddRq.ORSalesOrderLineAddList.Append.SalesOrderLineAdd

SalesOrderAddLn.ItemRef.FullName.SetValue("Merchandise")' This exists in QB item list
SalesOrderAddLn.Desc.SetValue("A Product")
SalesOrderAddLn.Amount.SetValue(10.00)

SalesOrderAddLn = SalesOrderAddRq.ORSalesOrderLineAddList.Append.SalesOrderLineAdd
SalesOrderAddLn.ItemRef.FullName.SetValue("Shipping")' This also in QB
SalesOrderAddLn.Desc.SetValue("Shipping")
SalesOrderAddLn.Amount.SetValue(12.00)

msgSetRs = sessManager.DoRequests(requestMsgSet)
Console.WriteLine("Quickbooks Sales Order Lines Created")
```

Comment: The issue was with the CustomerRef.FullName portion to the left of the : not existing yet.  Trying to create a customer and a job at the same time does not work.  I created the customer in QB (StoreName in the code above), and things worked.  It created the job (JobName in the code above), and processed the rest of the SalesOrder correctly.  Why it will create only the job portion escapes me. Any info on that is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Quickbooks returns success or failure in of the Response objects of the MessageSetResponse.ResponseList. So in your example, replace the last line in sales-order-creation method with the following to get the reason of the order not making it into QB.

```
Dim response As IResponse = msgSetRs.ReponseList.GetAt(0)
If response.StatusCode = 0 Then
  Console.WriteLine("Quickbooks Sales Order Lines Created")
Else
  Console.WriteLine("There was an error posting the sales order. " & response.StatusMessage)
End If
```

For the full list of QB status codes, see this page: https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbdesktop/docs/develop/exploring-the-quickbooks-desktop-sdk/status-codes-in-response-messages

P.S. my VB skills is a bit rustic; please fix it as needed :)

Comment: Thanks for that. It helped me track down the issue.  Added a comment to the original question.